# Xamarin.iOS app unable to deploy on iphone6s device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I've been trying to follow the guide to deploy an app from visual studio to an iphone using free provisioning. Steps -

1. Connect to Mac agent in Visual Studio 2015.[Success]
2. Create a demo app in Xcode with the *exactly* the same bundling name as the app I want to actually deploy.[Success]
3. Create a provisioning profile in Xcode for that demo app.(Using "fix issue").[Success]
4. Building the project in Visual Studio but it only runs if I select an emulator. It does not push to the device. [Fail]
5. I also tried making the same project (same bundling name) in Xamarin Studio in MAC. It *builds* successfully. But the same problem remains, it does not deploy to the actual device itself, only works if I select an emulator.[Fail]

The demo app I created(for free provisioning) gets successfully pushed to the device.

Am I missing an obvious step here?

Comment: What error does it give you when you try to deploy?

Comment: It does not give an error. I hit the run button with the device selected as iphone and VS and Xamarin Studio (in MAC) both of them just build the project unlike Xcode which actually pushes the app to the device.

Comment: This may sound silly, but I found - especially the first time - that it can take a nerve-wracking amount of time to push the app to an actual device. You say you don't get an error but does the build actually complete?

Comment: I think you cannot reuse the same bundle id for a different app.